# Unable to view entire width of Visual Studio property page

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 15. I am unable to view the entire width of the property page and hence the scroll bar on the right and property buttons on the right. I have dragged the page horizontally as far as it will go. Are there any options that will solve this? I already looked in Fonts and Colors.

My Windows text is 170% of the default normal size which is probably responsible for this but I need text this size because of my eyes.

[image: Visual Studio property page]

Comment: Resizing the dialog in width doesn't help?

Comment: this seems a bit sketchy, but can you try with a bigger screen resolution and or screen size?

Comment: Your eyes need a bigger monitor, nothing a couple of hundred bucks can't solve.

Comment: The dialog is resized horizontally as much as possible.

Comment: I can't imagine that Visual Studio is the only app that gives you problems with your system configured like this. I'm still young, so I can't sympathize with you on the eye problems (although I couldn't use a computer without glasses), but it looks to me like Hans is right: you simply need a bigger monitor. In the meantime, about the only thing you can do is slide the dialog back and forth using the title bar. Annoying yes, but at least you'd be able to switch categories, then interact with the options. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Fortunately, I make changes to the project properties very infrequently so it is not a serious issue. I have created another Windows user with a text size that is 120% of normal. I can login as that user to make changes if necessary. It is rare that I have a dialog problem like this. The developers of this property dialog should have added horizontal scrolling.